# How to call navigation action after click on item with RecyclerView and DataBinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, navigation

I have problem with call navigation action defined in nav_graph in my adpter.

I tried to call `Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id_myaction)`  in the `bind` function of the `ViewHolder` but it doesnt work and I got

> error : " View
>   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{96d8d23 V.E...C..
>   ...P.... 0,471-1080,628} does not have a NavController set"

It's my action:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/eventListFragment"
            android:name="EventListFragment"
            android:label="fragment_event_list"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_event_list" >
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_eventListFragment_to_startEventFragment"
                app:destination="@id/startEventFragment" />
</fragment>
```

It's my adapter:

```
class EventListAdapter(val findNavController: NavController) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EventListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var eventList:List<Event>


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): EventListAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val binding: EventListItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.event_list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding,findNavController)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EventListAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(eventList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if(::eventList.isInitialized) eventList.size else 0
    }

    fun updateEventList(eventList:List<Event>){
        this.eventList = eventList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: EventListItemBinding, val findNavController: NavController):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        private val viewModel = EventListItemViewModel()

        fun bind(event:Event){
            viewModel.bind(event)
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {v -> Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_eventListFragment_to_startEventFragment)}
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        }

    }
}
```

I would to start startEventFragment definied in my action after click on item.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate), you may require to change your code as follows,

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener {v ->
    v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_eventListFragment_to_startEventFragment) 
}
```

**Update**

If you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhost), you will find the following note,

> Note: The Navigation component is designed for apps that have one main
>   activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity is
>   associated with a navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment that
>   is responsible for swapping destinations as needed. In an app with
>   multiple activity destinations, each activity has its own navigation
>   graph.

So, you need to make sure that the both fragments belong to a same activity and the activity is associated with navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment. Please check if your activity's layout contains the following `fragment` tag,

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_id" />
```

Comment: @M.Devan I have updated my answer. If the problem still persists, can you share a little more code?

Comment: I found bug. I had was incorrectly initializing binding in my fragment

Answer (score 0):

The same problem, nothing helps me ...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView{a1d8ff1 VFE...C.. ...P.... 16,492-708,738 #7f0801ff app:id/tripLayout} does not have a NavController set

Solved
It was a problem with supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction.apply{}... in my MainActivity. Be careful. NavGaraph doesn't work if you have conflict between 2 types of fragments ...